# Code in Pinescript V5 in Tradingview check for Open=Low condition at one bar later

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to build a code in Pinescript V5 in Tradingview which check for a Open=Low condition one bar later. For example if Market open time is 9:15 AM, the code should fire only once at 9:16 AM to check if the previous bar (the bar at 9:15 AM) had Open=Low condition met

I could only frame till this part

```
//@version=5
indicator("Testing Alert on Open=Low", overlay=true)

var bool isLow_high = na
var bool alerted = false

// Market open time (adjust as per your market's opening time)
marketOpenTime = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 15)

// Detect if it's a new trading day
isNewDay = dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your conditions for the first bar of the session and check that with the history reference operator `[]` on the next bar to see if it was `true`.

Please note that, this will only work on the 1-min timeframe.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

marketOpenTime = (timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 09, 30) == time)
condition = (low == open)

was_condition_met_at_open = marketOpenTime[1] and condition[1]

plotshape(was_condition_met_at_open, "S", shape.triangledown, size=size.normal)
```

[image]

I had to change the start time to 09:30 as that's when the new day starts for this example.